# Cast pointer that isn't nil to BOOL returns NO

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

I've recently encountered a very rarely reproducible bug. If I cast a pointer that isn't nil to BOOL for some reason I get NO!!!11 I know that BOOL is typedef of signed char. Can that be a problem?

Comment: For posterity, would you mind including an example of how you cast to a BOOL? Using `(BOOL)var`?

Comment: Yeah. I'd expect that to give the wrong result. But I'd also expect just `BOOL b = var;` to work; if it didn't, I'd have a lot of code to fix. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pointer is of the form `0xNNNNNN00` or (on 64-bit) `0xNNNNNNNNNNNNNN00`, where `N` is any hex digit, then a cast to `BOOL` (an `unsigned char`) will leave you with `0` since it will truncate all the non-zero bits.

To properly convert a pointer to `BOOL`, use the inequality operator:

`BOOL isNotNull = (myPointer != NULL);`

Comment: Could you tell me "if (obj)" casts obj to what type?

Comment: You can act as if it casts to a `BOOL` through the inequality operator; in practice, it may or may not actually do that, depending on the system's instruction set. `if (aPointer)` should always work properly. :)

Answer (score 4):

Its because a pointer is 32 bit large and a char is just 8 bits. So when converting from a pointer to a char, it will trim 24 bits. So the possibility that the remaining 8 bits are just zeros is pretty high especially when the pointers address is high.

What you can do is the following:

```
BOOL myBool = (myPointer != NULL); // This will evaluate if the pointer is true (>0) or false (NULL)
```

Comment: @Jonathan: Sorry, it won't happen again. Promised :P

Answer (score 1):

`BOOL` is not a type that should be used, for this exact reason. In fact I can think of little use for a boolean-type variable (as opposed to just using the original value, pointer or whatever, on which it's based) except in the case of giant bit arrays where you'd need special code to address bits. If you really want a boolean type, use C99 `_Bool` (or `bool` in `stdbool.h`) which has the correct conversion semantics rather than modulo-256 reduction.